Power BI Embedded token
I implemented Power BI Embedded reporting using a service principle. I only have a 10$ pro account. Everything is working fine but I don't understand exactly the pricing.
So if I want to go in production do I need to but a A SKU capacity which is ~700$? I saw that there are 1000 tokens per days for free use. The reports would be used by 10 and they will generate max 20 reports/day
Thank you.

Yes for the use of embedded in Production you will need a capacity. The Pro license will allow you to develop the application etc, but the terms of do state that it needs to be moved to a capacity. If you are using an A SKU, you don’t have to have it on 24/7, it can be paused, for example outside of business hours, to reduce cost.
However MS will be deprecated the Power BI SKUs to Fabric, which do start at a lower cost.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/microsoft-fabric/

In PowerBi Embedded you pay for used hours. But Microsoft gives just API and a couple of buttons in Azure Portal for stopping/starting. So most clients pay a full monthly price. 
Another problem is in performance. If many users open a report at the same time it can just stuck and the error will tell that not enough resources, please change the plan.
Some products reduce the cost of PowerBi Embedded service significantly. 
An example is: https://genolis.com.au/smart-power-bi-embedded-manager-add-on
It starts/stops on demand and scales between plans when needed.
